# Prove that for $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} f'(x_{0}) \leftrightarrow \exists_{a \in \mathbb{R}} f(x_{0}+h) = f(x_{0})+a*h+R(h)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives, proof-verification

Prove that for $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \enspace f'(x_{0})$ exists and is finite $\Longleftrightarrow \exists_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \enspace f(x_{0}+h) = f(x_{0})+ah+R(h) \enspace $where $\frac{R(h)}{h} \to 0$ when $h \to 0$

---

Is my profe vaild?

We have to prove two implications:

$\Rightarrow)$ So from the definition of derivative we have that
$\enspace \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_{0} + h)-f(x_{0})}{h} = a \enspace$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ so it exists and is finite. If that is true we can find such function $R(h)$ for which equation will be like: 
$\enspace f(x_{0} + h)-f(x_{0})=ah+R(h) \Leftrightarrow f(x_{0} + h) = f(x_{0})+ah+R(h) \enspace$ but when $h \to 0$ then it must be that $\frac{R(h)}{h} \to 0$ what was to prove.

On the other hand

$\Leftarrow)$ We can rewrite this equation to:
$\enspace \frac{f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0})}{h}=a+\frac{R(h)}{h} \enspace$ and we have that $\frac{R(h)}{h} \to 0$ when $h \to 0$ so $\enspace \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0})}{h} \enspace$ is equal to $a$ which is (by definition) finite. As we have that and we use derivative definition, we can say that 
$\enspace f'(x_{0}) \enspace$ exists and is finite. What was to prove.

Comment: (1) In $\;\implies\;$ , why the (finite) existence of that limit implies the existence of that function $\;R(h)\;$ of $\;h\;$ ? And how, and why is this allowed, you passed from $$\lim_{h\to\ 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}h=a\;\;\text{to}\;\;f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)=ah+R(h)\;\;?$$I'd say that if the function $\;R\;$ exists then $$\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}h=a\implies f(x_0)-f(x_0)=ah+hR(h)\ldots\;\text{or what happened here?}$$Some more thorough explanation may be needed here, depending on how things were learnt.

Comment: I don't know how to show that such function exists but is quite natural that we can find it that for every $h$ it will be true because it will looks like:
$R(h)=f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0})-ah$

Comment: **That exactly** could be your function's definition! It works, it is nice, it even is continuous in some neighborhood of $\;x_0\;$ , etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ad $\Rightarrow:\quad$ When $f'(x_0)=a$ you don't have to "find" the function $h\mapsto R(h)$. You can define $R$ right away by the formula in the title:
$$R(h):=f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)- a\>h\ .$$Then you have to prove that $\lim_{h\to0} {R(h)\over h}=0$, which should not be too difficult.

Ad $\Leftarrow:\quad$o.k.